# Import a table changing it to ROWDEPENDCIES

Tags: oracle

I am importing the below table , `TEST_M`, I want while importing it to change it to  `ROWDEPENDCY`

```
impdp system/pass dumpfile=TEST.dmp directory=EXPORT logfile=ilog.log tables=schema.TEST full= Y
```

creation of the table is like below , I was thinking about using TRANSFORM parameter

```
create table TEST  (x var number) rowdependencies;

 TRANSFORM=ROWDEPENDCY:n:TEST
```

but not sure what to add in it.

Comment: There is no datapump transformation to affect `ROWDEPENDENCIES`.  Why don't you import the table with no rows, change it via online redefinition, and then import the rows?

Comment: ROWDEPENDCY is used for normal insert update. What exactly you wanted to achieve here

Comment: well what I did is creating the table as rowdependecy , then I import the dump with TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND. @MatthewMcPeak

Comment: well I have a dump table that i want to import it into a database. however this table is not rowdependcy, so how to change that ?, I want this table to imported as rowdependcy,. so what I did I created the table empty then I emported it with table_exists_action = append